# condicional IF en EXCEL desde otra hoja

Tags: excel

La pregunta es muy fácil pero es difícil de explicar, Solo tenganme paciencia. Resulta que quiero hacer una simple base de datos en EXCEL para una venta de tortas.

Aqui está la captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resulta que en el campo producto tengo una lista de los postres, pero esta lista se encuentra en otra hoja de excel (esto lo realicé con la herramienta validacion de datos ) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la hoja "costos de los productos" quiero poner cuantos productos tengo y el precio de cada uno. La siguiente imagen es un screenshot de la hoja "costos de los productos" :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente lo que quiero es hacer una formula en la cual cuando elija una opción en el campo "Producto" automaticamente se inserte el precio del producto en el campo "Costo del producto"

Por ejemplo: Si en la lista del campo "Producto" selecciono "Torta de chocolate" , Entonces que en el campo "Costo del producto" se ponga Automaticamente el numero 1 (porque cuesta un dolar).

En el siguiente capture muestra como intenté poner un formula para realizarlo, pero me muestra un error y no se como hacer :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar les estaría muy agradecido, porque estoy sufriendo por eso. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una recomendación seria: Excel **no** es un programa para hacer bases de datos. Es una hoja de cálculo, que no es lo mismo. Desconozco las dimensiones de tu proyecto y todas las tablas que necesitarás, pero te recomiendo encarecidamente que si quieres tener una bbdd sólida, **no utilices Excel**. Puedes recurrir a soluciones gratuitas con formación online como Access, SQL, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ese fue mi primer pensamiento. Pero no lo administraré yo, sino la dueña del emprendimiento. Entonces solo quiero cosas con cero complejidad, nada de base de datos tipo mongo, SQL, etc. Ademas es para que cada venta de tortas que haga las anote directamente en su celular (muchas ventas seran a domicilio), y como tiene un IPHONE quiero hacer esa data base en google spreadsheet que es gratis, y luego importarlo en pandas, Python, etc para hacer los analisis.

Answer (score 7):

con la función VLOOKUP (BUSCARV en español) podrías hacerlo mas fácilmente.

Seria mas o menos... `=BUSCARV(C2, "costos de los productos"!A1:B3, 2,0)`

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Aunque me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Sin embargo, con el metodo de tomy me sale sin errores. (Aunque todavia no lo he podido implementar bien). Porque crees que sea ese error ?

Comment: Eise Muchisimas gracias. A todos les digo que el problema es que las comillas dobles las tenia que cambiar por comillas simples, y separar los argumentos con punto y coma

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero sería dar nombres a los rangos con los que vas a trabajar en la hoja ventas (TipoProducto y CosteProducto).
Esto hará mucho más sencillo mecanizar fórmulas largas y evitar errores.

**Edito para añadir cuales son los rangos**

En este 'libro' tienes los datos en la taba 'COSTOS DE LOS PRODUCTOS', y como ahí es dónde tenemos que buscar, es dónde creamos los rangos.
La columna 'A' es el rango `TipoProducto` y para crearlo puedes seleccionar todas las filas que quieras (o la columna completa si quieres) Ahora tienes que buscar la opción 'Crear Intervalos y expresiones con nombre' y directamente te crea el rango con el nombre de que tengas en la primera fila. Puedes seleccionar las columnas 'A' y 'B' completas y así crear los dos a la vez. Sí te comento que los rangos no van a tener espacios, yo suelo utilizar los nombres como en programación, palabras juntas con la primera letra en mayúsculas.

No te puedo decir exactamente dónde está ese menú porque no tengo excel a mano.

**Importante que los dos rangos deben tener la misma longitud de filas.**

Luego Indice - Coincidir
y comprobar si está la celda acupada y posibles errores como la falta de algún precio.

```
INDICE(CosteProducto;COINCIDIR(C2;TipoProducto;0))
```

`Coincidir` busca el valor de `C2` en el rango de celdas `TipoProducto`. El valor '0' hace que la busqueda sea una coincidencia exacta.

```
COINCIDIR(C2;TipoProducto;0)
```

`Coincidir` devuelve la fila en que está el resultado de la búsqueda.

```
INDICE(CosteProducto;COINCIDIR(C2;TipoProducto;0))
```

Ahora ya función completa. `CosteProcucto` es el rango en que tienes los precios. `Indice` nos devuelve lo que hay en la fila que nos dice `Coincidir`.

Como no quieres la hoja llena de datos con errores envuelves todo entre un `Si('cadenaVacía', 'cadenaVacía', pero si hay datos ejecuta)`

```
SI(C2="";"";INDICE(CosteProducto;COINCIDIR(C2;TipoProducto;0)))
```

Aún puedes tener algún error, te falta por añadir algún dato o se te borró accidentalmente.
Pues lo envuelves todo en un `Si.Error()`

```
=SI.ERROR(SI(C2="";"";INDICE(CosteProducto;COINCIDIR(C2;TipoProducto;0)));"No está el precio")
```

Esta sería la fórmula final de la casilla D2 de la hoja VENTAS. Arrastras y no verás nada hasta que rellenes el campo C2

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias. Pero cuando implemento tu formula me sale "No está el precio". Me inmagino porque los rangos no los nombré (CosteProducto,TipoProducto). Estoy un poco confundido. Como lo harias Sin los nombres TipoProducto Y costeProducto ) ?

Comment: Otra cosa es que no veo en ninguna parte de la formula que te hayas metido a la hoja "Costo de los productos", Como entonces sabrias cuanto se tiene que poner (cuanto vale el producto) en la casilla "costo de los productos" (casilla D ) de la hoja ventas ?. . Otra cosa es que ya asigné  nombre a los rangos y ahora no sale nada. . . Estoy bastante confundido.

Comment: Edito la respuesta que igual no expliqué cuales son los nombres de los rengos

Comment: te digo un dato de un problema que tengo :   que el problema es que las comillas dobles las tengo que cambiar por comillas simples, y para separar los argumentos tengo que separarlos con punto y coma ( ; ).  . . Es un problema con la configuracion de mi computadora (ya creo que lo resolví), sin embargo las preguntas anteriores que te realicé siguen en pie

Comment: @NIN la fórmula sin rangos quedaría algo así como =INDICE($'COSTOS DE LOS PROCUCTOS'.B$2:B$200;COINCIDIR(C2;$'COSTOS DE LOS PROCUCTOS'.A$2:A$200;0)) y falta añadir el control de errores. Con los rangos no solo acortas el código, evitas errores en la búsqueda y facilitas la comprensión. A ver si ahora puedes crear los rangos

Comment: Tu solucion me sigue pareciendo bastante robusta. Aunque todavia se me ha hecho dificil de implementar. Deja unos dias a ver si podria implementarla. En serio muchas gracias por todo ese esfuerzo.