# Valorar y buscar el valor del medio como si de un juego de barcos se tratara en EXCEL

Tags: excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la siguiente lista y trato de que una vez escogido un valor en el campo talla y producto de la tabla de abajo me saque en el campo código el valor que se encuentra entre ambas. Como si de un juego de barcos se tratara. Pero no sé ni que aplicar ni como hacerlo ...

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para buscar un campo de una matriz que coincida con la fila y columna, puedes usar las funciones Buscarv y coincidir ambas combinadas; para el caso de tu ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente forma (supongamos que tu matriz comienza en la celda A1, entonces la celda donde quieres que va el código estaría en la D8)
=BUSCARV(A8;A1:D4;COINCIDIR(B8;A1:D1;0);0)
Donde:
A8: es el valor a buscar en tu fila
A1:D4 es la matriz
B8: es el valor a buscar en las columnas

Puedes revisar el siguiente [enlace](https://www.saberprogramas.com/buscar-por-fila-y-columna-en-excel-buscarv-y-coincidir-2/)

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta de @Joshin, es una de las formas de hacerlo abreviado y fácil

Pero hay alguna más, una de las alternativas, para que te puedas ir haciendo una idea de como se manejan las funciones condicionales podría ser (Todo seguido):

```
=SI(Y(B10="l";C10="camiseta");B4;SI(Y(B10="l";C10="pantalón");C4;
SI(Y(B10="l";C10="chaqueta");D4;SI(Y(B10="m";C10="camiseta");B5;
SI(Y(B10="m";C10="pantalón");C5;SI(Y(B10="m";C10="chaqueta");D5;
SI(Y(B10="s";C10="camiseta");B6;SI(Y(B10="s";C10="pantalón");C6;
SI(Y(B10="s";C10="chaqueta");D6;"ERROR")))))))))
```

Lo que hacemos es condicionar, que si en la celda B10 hay una "l" y en la celda C10 "camiseta", seleccione el contenido de la celda B4.

Si no se cumple la condición anterior, vuelve a preguntar si en la celda B10 hay una "l" y en la celda C10 "pantalón", selecciona el código de la celda C4

Así se iría preguntando sucesivamente una y otra vez si coinciden los dos parámetros, talla y prenda para ir seleccionando el código correspondiente

Evidentemente, el primer método es más rápido, sencillo y efectivo, pero te he puesto éste otro para darte más posibilidades y puntos de vista

Un saludo

Answer (score 4):

Para solucionar ciertos problemas con las funciones `BUSCARV` o `BUSCARH` están las funciones `INDICE - COINCIDIR`.

En tu propuesta la fórmula sería:

```
=INDICE($B$2:$D$4;COINCIDIR(A8;A$2:A$4;0);COINCIDIR(B8;$B1:$D1;0))
```

Según la información de microsoft:

```
INDICE(matriz; núm_fila; [núm_columna])
```

Le dices toda la matriz en la que están el conjunto de datos y luego en la fila y columna en que está el dato.

En tu caso es `=INDICE($B$2:$D$4; 2; 2)`

Para saber la fila y columna tienes la función `COINCIDIR`:

```
COINCIDIR(valor_buscado; rango de busqueda; [tipo_de_coincidencia])

COINCIDIR(A8; A$2:A$4; 0)
```

Busca la "talla M" (A8) en el rango de filas de las tallas (A$2:A$4) con una **"coincidencia exacta"**  (0)

Para buscar la columna se repite la función `COINCIDIR`

```
COINCIDIR(B8; $B1:$D1; 0)
```

Busca "pantalones" (B8) en el rango de los "tipos de ropa" ($B1:$D1) con una **"coincidencia exacta"**  (0)

Tienes otro ejemplo en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/461775/condicional-if-en-excel-desde-otra-hoja/461997#461997)