# Como autorrellenar celdas con los días de la semana según el día de la celda anterior

Tags: excel

En un fichero excel que estoy elaborando, tengo un calendario con los días del mes:

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13 ...

Deseo poner debajo de cada día del mes, la inicial del día de la semana

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 ...

l  m  x  j  v  s  d  l  m   x  j  v  s ...

En la fila 3 tengo los números del mes, en la fila 4 quería poner los días de la semana

Se me ocurre poner en la B4:

```
=SI(A4="l";"m";"x")
```

Pero que valor tengo que poner en falso, porque si pongo "x", si cambio la "l" por cualquier otra letra en la celda A4, siempre me escribe "x"

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos

En tu función SI, lo que le estas condicionando, es que si pones una "l" en la celda anterior, te ponga una "m", y si no es una "l", te ponga una "x", pero claro, esa condición sería para cualquier otra letra que no sea "l", incluso me aventuraría a decir que para cualquier otro carácter que no sea una "l", o sea, números, símbolos ...

Tu función SI() estaría bien orientada, pero deberías de continuar enlazando la misma función en caso de no cumplirse la anterior

O sea, si es "l" (SI(A4="l"), pon "m", pero si no es "l" y vuelves a iniciar una nueva función, Si es "m" (SI(A4="m", pones "x", si no lo es, inicias de nuevo la función, si es "x" SI(A4="x", pones "j", y si no lo es, y así sucesivamente en cada espacio reservado de la función y si no lo es, comienzas la nueva condición pasando por todas las posibilidades.

Cuando se acaben, como no hay datos que mostrar, simplemente pones que si no es ninguna letra de las iniciales de los días de la semana, no pones nada "", o puedes poner "ERROR" o lo que quieras, pero teniendo en cuenta que se vea dentro de la celda

Esta sería la fórmula correcta:

```
=SI(A4="l";"m";SI(A4="m";"x";SI(A4="x";"j";SI(A4="j";"v";SI(A4="v";"s";SI(A4="s";"d";SI(A4="d";"l";"")))))))
```

Aquí estamos diciento que si es "l", nos ponga "m", si no es "l" y es "m", nos ponga "x", si no es "l", no es "m", pero es "x", nos ponga "j", etc, etc

Más o menos, estaríamos empleando el "else if" de los lenguajes de programación, o sea, empieza por la primera condición SI, si no se cumple, salta a la siguiente, si tampoco se cumple, a la siguiente, y así sucesivamente hasta que encuentre una coincidiencia y si no, no pondría nada, "".

Esa fórmula la deberías de pegar en cada celda de la fila 4 que se sitúe debajo de cada número del calendario. Creo haber entendido que si pones de forma manual la inicial del día de la semana en la celda A4 desearías cambiar el resto de celdas a continuación de la primera (A4, B4, C4, ...)

Espero sea lo que buscas

Comment: Gracias @trasgu, entendido.

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a hacer un calendario lo mejor es **utilizar fechas** con los formatos adecuados.

La lista de números puedes poner en la celda `A1`  `01/07/2021` y luego ir a **formato de celda** y poner `D` . Esto te pondrá `1`
Celda `B1` `=A1+1`  **formato de celda** `D` . Esto te pondrá `2`  y aunque visualizas un número tienes la fecha correcta.

Si te valiesen 3 letras sería volver a hacer lo mismo en la **fila2**, pero ahora en el **formato de celda** pones `NN` . el resultado sería `jue`.

Para una sola letra es un poco más complicado, pero puedes crear una tabla aparte, donde no te moleste, con los valores del día de la semana. Yo la creé en las columnas `AA`y `AB`
1 L 2 M 3 X....

Ahora volviendo a la **fila2** utilizas `INDICE - COINCIDIR´ y listo.

La fórmula sería algo así como `=INDICE(AB$1:AB$7;COINCIDIR(DIASEM(A1;2);AA$1:AA$7;0))`

Según la configuración de tu hoja puedes tener que cambiar los '**;**'(punto y coma) por '**,**' (coma).

[para más info sobre INDICE - COINCIDIR](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463042/valorar-y-buscar-el-valor-del-medio-como-si-de-un-juego-de-barcos-se-tratara-en/463939#463939)

[y aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/461775/condicional-if-en-excel-desde-otra-hoja/461997#461997)